# KendoUI > Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'level'

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using KendoUI MVC, I use a TreeView in my PartialView but when page is loaded in browser tree view "loading..." is displaying and there is an error in chrome inspector:
Uncaught TypeError: Object no method 'level'

I add kendo.all.min.js & kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js to my layout & I'm using kendo 2013.3.1119

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, added (PHP)

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

before sending anything else to the browser and it did the trick